# list servers OrientDB 2.2. via http rest

Tags: orientdb

i try to get servers status of distributed version of OrientDB via http rest  :

```
curl --user admin:admin --header "Accept: text/csv" -d "list servers " "http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql"
```

doesnt works :

```
{
  "errors": [
{
  "code": 500,
  "reason": 500,
  "content": "com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.list servers\u000d\u000a\u0009DB name=\"GratefulDeadConcerts\""
}
```

Comment: oups, it s version 2.2.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're sending a `list servers` command to the sql interpreter while that's not a sql command but a console one.

---

**UPDATE**

you can use this

```
curl --user root:root --header "Accept: text/csv" -d "HA STATUS -servers -output=text" "http://localhost:2480/command/GratefulDeadConcerts/sql"
```

Comment: any idea for get status of servers with Api rest ?

Comment: `curl --user root:root --header "Accept: text/csv"  "http://localhost:2480/server"`    http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html

Comment: thanks a lot Ivan, but this doesnt return status of each servers

Comment: you can refer to this if you need more details. http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-HA-Status.html

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to get the results as JSON that contains all servers (nodes) with detailed status and info per server:

```
curl -X POST --user {{user}}:{{password}} --header "Accept: application/json" \
     -d "HA STATUS -servers -db" "{{orientdb-url}}:2480/command/{{database-name}}/sql"
```